# How do i close shut down my application from another Form?

Tags: c#

I have this event in a new Form:

```
private void CrawlLocaly_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Im not sure if to use Closed or Closing. 
The reason is that i want to check if the user shut down the program for example by just closing the application from the taskbar.

If he did close it from the taskbar mouse right click then close then i want it to close all the program and not only this Form.

How can i do it ?

Comment: Also in Form1 i used Closed event not Closing. When do i need to use Closed and when Closing ? If the user just close the program from the program it self by clicking top right red X or just Exit from the menu  that is Closing ? And if the user shutdown the program without exit just from the taskbar mouse right click > Close that's Closed or closing too ?

Comment: `FormClosing` allows you to conditionally cancel the `FormClosed` event. The `FormClosed` event indicates that the `Form` has been closed by any means.

Comment: Does it matter how the application was closed?

Comment: I don't think you can differentiate the facts that the user closed the application either via the X button on the form, or via the "Close window" item that is in the right click menu of the taskbar. The only info you're gonna get are in the [`CloseReason`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.closereason.aspx) object that you can retrieve via the FormClosing/FormClosed events.

Comment: As Otiel says. However you could check the Cursor.Position in the event but I wouldnt suggest it as a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    Application.Exit();
```

Will shut down your application.
Im not really sure if you can detect if he closed it via rightmouse menu. As far as I know you can only see the reasons provided in the FormClosedEventArgs. FormClosing will provide you with same reasons.

Comment: The title and the question don't seem to match, and this only answers the title.

Comment: Im aware of that it doesnt give a solution to detect if he has used rightclick on the taskmenu. But is there any way to actually do that? Other than the closereason UserClosing which will be set even if the users decides to close it with other means.

Answer (score 0):

Use this event:

```
private void Form_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
    {
         //close forms
         Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

There is no way to check whether user closed your form by clicking 'X' or through `TaskBar` or any other way as the result of `CloseReason` will always be `CloseReason.UserClosing`

Answer (score 0):

Well I Stick with such issue also. 
In mine app I have 2 forms, #1 main, #2 - for settings - if user close it i want to know save settings or not. Also if settings are null - close app not only form, if user click button save - I want to close (hide) #2 form. 
So where is my solution we set tag value to 1 if click button save, so we will know "who" try to close form:
Predefined:

```
btnSave.Tag = 0;
```

On save button click event:

```
btnSave.Tag = 1;
this.Hide();
```

its will trigger onclose event:

```
private void frmLogin_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (btnSave.Tag.ToString() == "0")
        {
            DialogResult dlg = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to exit without finished setup connection?", "Form", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            if (dlg == DialogResult.No)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Cancel = false;
                this.Dispose();
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
```